# Working with multiple branches and getting extra files in my push

Tags: git

I'm new to git and I'm only using command line to learn how it works.
The problem I'm having is, I have multiple git branches and files I don't want are ending up in my pushes.
I have branch "A" and I do some work. I commit and push my changes. Then I do 'git fetch' and 'git checkout B' to get my co-workers branch "B" to build and run locally. I then 'git checkout master' and 'git pull origin master' and get latest in my master to verify something that's current. The problem is then I go back to 'git checkout A' and make a change and add and commit it. At this point when I push to that branch i typically find I have all kinds of other files that are in my push. I don't want this. How can I avoid this? I know I'm doing something wrong but not sure what.
Also any links to tutorials you think are applicable is appreciated.

Comment: I can recommend this "book" for really learning how git works. While not *that* long it digs deep and has easy-to-follow examples building on each other. At the end at least I felt a lot more comfortable doing "everyday magic" with git: http://www.ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf

Comment: Could you update your question with what commands you used to add and commit stuff? It would help us get more clues on how you end up in the situation you describe.

Comment: My issue was not using 'git fetch' the first time. Everything actually worked. Sorry for this!

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to do "fetch" previously. When I actually followed the steps I wrote in the question, it worked. That's when I realized my previous mistake. Thanks Jonas, for the book recommendation. I just downloaded it.